# Javascript arrow function with map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I wanted to understand in depth why this works
`[0, 1, 2].map(i => i + 1)`
but this doesn't
`[0, 1, 2].map(i => {i + 1})`

I had this problem when I was working on a jQuery script. I tried to use a map with an arrow function to extract `$(this).data('id')` from checkboxes and we got an array of undefined. About an hour later by pure luck we copy pasted some stack code and notices the only difference was the `function() {}` so now i'm wondering why? Is it bad to use arrow functions? is it not compatible?

For the record I am using Google Chrome Version 66

Comment: `{return i+1}` ... it's part of the syntax `() => { statements }` - if you want to return something inside `{}` you have to explicitly return it ... fact is the code you posted that works is the "shorthand" (advanced syntax) version of arrow notation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: ^, arrow functions without braces have an implicit return.

Comment: `Is it bad to use arrow functions? is it not compatible?` No, it's not *bad* nor incompatible assuming you've done the bare minimum reading on how arrow functions work...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Its an ES6 arrow function syntax difference. Add a 'return' and you will get the response `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`

```
[0, 1, 2].map(i => {return i + 1})
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Thanks

Comment: Or remove the `{}` ... `[0, 1, 2].map(i =>  i + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of syntaxes for arrow functions 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

The first one has an implied return of the expression value.  The syntax with { ... } doesn't, so you need to supply it explicitly.